# vertically aligning a div within a parent

Tags: html, css

I would like to vertically align the div ".person-user" so that is vertically in the center of the parent element ".person" (The text to be in the center of the photo but to the right) How can I do this?

Thanks

http://jsfiddle.net/mpBW5/5/

Comment: Is javascript allowed? You can use suggested solutions, but I don't like them. Taking a div and displaying it AS IF it is a table? Nah.

Comment: @BramVanroy I guess involving a virtual machine *on your users browser* running cryptic soup of parentheses and dollar signs through 32Kb client side library is much better than displaying a `div` as a table (using a facility designed for just that). Right.

Comment: @amn I don't know where you get the idea of a virtual machine but a browser doesn't use the resources of a virtual machine when running simple jQuey. Also, `display: table` etc. is **not** designed to 'transform' block elements. It is designed as a default value for tables. Easy as that. When you are giving that div a `display: table-cell`, why wouldn't you just change the HTML to a table? Because tables are not meant for that kind of content. *Nor is its default display value made for normal content such as images*!

Comment: I get the idea of a virtual machine from reading about JavaScript engines. Granted, most of these today are just-in-time compilers, but that's still a substantial overhead and bytecode interpreting. And users feel it. And I hope you know that JQuery runs on top of your JavaScript engine, so there is an additional (leaking) abstraction layer. Additionally, `display:table` does not transform elements, it aids in displaying them. The reason not to change into a table is because `TABLE` or `TD` carry **different semantics** in a document than a `DIV` element being displayed as a table or a cell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The most precise way is to do this with jQuery and calculate it dynamically for each div. This is useful if some/all image/text divs have different heights. The [example](http://jsfiddle.net/mpBW5/15/). The code:

```
$("div.person-user").each(function() {
    $(this).css("marginTop", function() {
        var imgH = $(this).prev("div.person-user-pic").height(),
        thisH = $(this).height(),
        h = (imgH/2) - (thisH/2);
    return h;
    });
});​
```

BUT: if every div and image has the same height, you could just do this:

```
div.person-user {margin-top: 8px;}
```

I hope that this answers your question?

Answer (score 1):

This is something that should be simple, but is actually a pain in the backside to do. Here's a quick jsFiddle, using display: table on the person div, and display: table-cell on the picture wrapper and info divs:

http://jsfiddle.net/2yfDs/1/

Answer (score 1):

What follows is a combination of markup and style that will accomplish exactly what you want, **without JavaScript and JQuery**.

#### Markup:

```
<div class="person">
    <img class="profile" src="http://sphotos-a.xx.fbcdn.net/hphotos-ash4/320450_10151028382307410_534533150_n.jpg"/>
    <div class="profile">
        <div class="name">Colin Pacelli</div>
        <div class="fact">Ohio University</div>
    </div>
</div>​​​​​​​
```

#### Style:

```
.person {
    display: table;
}

.person img.profile{
    height: 50px;
    margin-right: 10px;
    /*border-radius: 4px 4px 4px 4px;*/
}

.person div.profile {
    display: table-cell;
    vertical-align: middle;
    /*font-family: calibri;
    font-size: 14px;
    color: #444;*/
}

/*.person .profile .name {
    font-weight: bold;
}*/
```

I have commented out the rules that do not principally affect the solution, so that all can see how little it takes with CSS if done right. Compared to 10 lines of code running using 32Kb of client side code running on top of a virtual machine. And you thought Adobe Flash Player was evil. I do not mind JQuery much, especially for things it can do well, but frankly, involving JQuery in a clear cut case of pure style is a just bit too much.

As you probably can figure, I have edited your JSFiddle, stripping it of non-essentials and cutting it down to a minimal example that exhibits the desired behavior while leaving the visuals in place.

Since you specified `html` and `css` as tags, and since it is in nearly all cases a better idea not to resort to JavaScript/JQuery when they can be avoided, I would really use a markup and style solution like the above instead.

Answer (score 0):

This is a very common question and the best explanation so far is here:

http://phrogz.net/css/vertical-align/index.html